# Ant Forms: Why the values are different Need Explanation?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Here code have two console log 1 and 2 but actual result should be same but comes out different when deleting the user
Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/control-between-forms-ant-design-demo-6q86b?file=/index.js:2828-3696

````
            let users = getFieldValue("users") || [];
            const handleClick = id => {
              setFieldsValue({
                users: users.filter(item => item.name !== id)
              });
              console.log("1" + users);
            };
            console.log("2" + users);

            return users.length ? (
              <ul>
                {users.map((user, index) => (
                  <li key={index} className="user">
                    <Avatar icon={<UserOutlined />} />
                    {user.name} - {user.age}
                    <CloseOutlined
                      onClick={() => handleClick(user.name)}
                      style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}
                    />
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `handleClick` is bound when `users` have (for example) 2 users.  When you delete one, you print 2 users and then 1 is removed, which causes a re-render. This prompts the second console.log, which prints 1 user (and re-binds the function with the new result of `let users = getFieldValue("users") || [];`

I'm not sure if you use setState, but if you do: setState doesn't update straight away; it's asynchronous, so you cannot check the value the line after your set-statement.